# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported while running API using POSTMAN Client

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, postman

I am executing a rest API with help of postman client as part of testing my Spring MVC application.

While testing the GET APIs I am getting correct response but while I am making a POST request through POSTMAN client I am getting 405 error

Following are my files:

**WebController**:

```
    package com.websystique.springsecurity.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;





import com.websystique.springsecurity.model.Operations;
import com.websystique.springsecurity.service.KeywordService;
import com.websystique.springsecurity.service.OperationService;

@RestController
public class WebserviceController {

    @Autowired
    KeywordService keywordService;

    @Autowired
    OperationService operationService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/webservice/keywords", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> listAllKeywords() {
        List<String> keywords = keywordService.listAllKeywords();
        if(keywords.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(keywords, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/webservice/findalloperations",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Operations>> findAllOperations() {
        List<Operations> operations =  operationService.findAllOperations();
        if(operations.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Operations>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Operations>>(operations, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/webservice/getOperation" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Operations> findOperationByKeyword(@RequestBody String keyword) {

        System.out.println("Running webservice for keyword" + keyword);
        Operations operation = operationService.findOperationByKeyword(keyword);
        if(operation == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Operations>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Operations>(operation,HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/webservice/getOperation/{keyword}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Operations> findOperationByKeywordGet(@PathVariable String keyword) {

        System.out.println("Running webservice for keyword" + keyword);
        Operations operation = operationService.findOperationByKeyword(keyword);
        if(operation == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Operations>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Operations>(operation,HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/webservice/getAllOperationNames" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> findAllOperationName() {

        System.out.println("Getting all operation names");
        List<String> operationnames = operationService.findAllOperationName();
        if(operationnames.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(operationnames,HttpStatus.OK);

    }


}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer**

```
package com.websystique.springsecurity.configuration;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

**SecurityConfiguration:**

```
package com.websystique.springsecurity.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Ashvarya").password("ashvarya123").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("root123").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("root123").roles("ADMIN","DBA");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
      //----------------------------------------------------------
        .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/webservice/**").permitAll()
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/protected/**").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

    }
}
```

**CORSFilter:**

```
package com.websystique.springsecurity.configuration;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Filtering on...........................................................");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

POST URL: http://localhost:8080/AutomationToolWebPortal/webservice/getOperation

POST Request:

```
    {

    "keyword":"Click"
}
```

**RESPONSE HEADERS RECIEVED:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → x-requested-with, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Access-Control-Max-Age → 3600
Allow → GET
Cache-Control → no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language → en
Content-Length → 1090
Content-Type → text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date → Fri, 11 Sep 2015 10:36:06 GMT
Expires → 0
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options → nosniff
X-Frame-Options → DENY
X-XSS-Protection → 1; mode=block
```

I have gone through different answers for this question but most of them talk about sending csrfilter in request. Not sure how to do that in postman.
Please help

Comment: Have you tried only POSTing "Click"? The request body you are posting is probably assuming it will be marshalled to an Object with a single field called 'keyword'.

Comment: I want to post only one POST variable "keyword" in the request. I have tried with different values for "Keyword" but the result is same.

Comment: Create a class called MyClass with only one field - a String called keyword. And then change the argument type at @RequestBody from String to MyClass

Comment: I was able to get rid of error 500 by turning the CSRF filer off in my SecurityConfiguration file and now when I run the API using POSTMAN I am able to do that without any issue. I guess I can keep it off for testing purpose and turn it on in the production environment.

Also, thanks @morsor the point you mentioned about MyClass is also correct one. I got an error after turning CSRF off that value of keyword was not set and when I make argument of my post method RequestBody to MyClass then it is working fine. Thanks for your help!!